# Backspace keyReleased issue

Tags: java, awt, keylistener

So, I have a bunch of textfields and comboboxes created programatically, arranged on 3 columns. There can be as many rows as the user needs. I made it so that when the user presses `Tab` or `Enter` to jump to the next textfield/combobox. The user can select from the options menu if he wants the `keyListener` to react to keyPressed(for it to jump continuously while being pressed) or on keyReleased(to only jump once even if he keeps the key pressed) I did the same for backspace,if the textfield has no text ( `== ""` ) it will jump back to the previous textfield. 
Now, my issue is this :

Lets say a textfield has the text "foo".When the user focuses the textfield,the whole text will be selected.If the user presses backspace,it will delete the text and when the user releases the backspace it will jump back to the previous textfield since the textfield is empty at the moment he releases.

This is not good,for me at least.I want it so that when the text gets selected and the user presses backspace the text should be erased but it shouldn't jump back.It should jump back on the next keyReleased.

I don't want to use keyPressed,or at least give him the option not to do that, becacuse the user might accidentally keep the key pressed for too long and it will delete like 3 textfields.

I guess i could make the keyPressed only react once thru some conditions but i'd like to explore other options since i want to get used to finding the best solutions,the solutions that were ment for my issues and  and not scratch my head the other way around.

this is how i'm changing focus :

```
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
    if (prefs.getBoolean("cbBackspace2", false) == true) {
        if (prefs.getBoolean("cbBackspace", false) == true) {
            String curca = currentview.getName();
            String intValue = curca.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "");
            int foo = Integer.parseInt(intValue);
            if (currentview.getText().equals("") && foo != 1) {
                allpret.get(foo - 2).requestFocus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE or MCVE or MCTaRE